# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Citrix to set up the framework, but it's not running at all.

I get the exception

```
unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

I have tried all the following things.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I need a solution for this.

Comment: I'm working in a Citrix environment. this is quite different. Browser's data storedd in some other server so we cant access those.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

It works for me.